# Dephasing noise as a decoherence model - Effect on a generalized GHZ state

Tags: quantum-information, decoherence, noise

**Some input:**

Consider a decoherence process modelled by $$\mathcal{E}\left(\rho\right)=p_0\rho+(1-p_0)\sigma_z\rho\sigma_z$$ with $p_0=(1+e^{-\gamma t})/2$. One can readily find that this leads to $\mathcal{E}\left(|i\rangle\langle i|\right)=|i\rangle\langle i|$ for $i=0,1$ and $\mathcal{E}\left(|i\rangle\langle j|\right)=e^{-\gamma t}|i\rangle\langle j|$ for $i\neq j;i,j=0,1$. With the linearity of the quantum operation $\mathcal{E}$, properties of tensor products and $\mathcal{E}^{\otimes n}(\sigma^{\otimes n})=[\mathcal{E}(\sigma)]^{\otimes n}$ one readily finds that the effect of $\mathcal{E}^{\otimes n}$ on a GHZ state $$|GHZ\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle^{\otimes n}+|1\rangle^{\otimes n}\right)$$ can be evaulated by only looking at the "off diagonal terms" in the density matrix (regarding the computational basis $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$) $$\rho=\frac{1}{2}\left(|0\rangle\langle 0|^{\otimes n}+|1\rangle\langle 0|^{\otimes n}+|0\rangle\langle 1|^{\otimes n}+|1\rangle\langle 1|^{\otimes n}\right),$$ since the others don't change.

We have $\mathcal{E}^{\otimes n}\left(|0\rangle\langle 1|^{\otimes n}\right)=\left[e^{-\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle 1|\right]^{\otimes n}=e^{-n\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle 1|$. The exponential factor is considered as the decoherence rate of the ghz state, since it determines how quickly the state becomes maximally mixed (in the computational basis $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$ I assume). So far so good.

Now consider the generalized ghz state $$|GHZ\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{K}}\left(|0\rangle^{\otimes n}+|\epsilon\rangle^{\otimes n}\right)$$ with $|\epsilon\rangle=\cos\epsilon|0\rangle+\sin\epsilon|1\rangle$ and some $K$ to normalize the state.

**Question:**

Is it true, that one can (here) also consider only the "off diagonal terms" $|0\rangle\langle\epsilon|$ to compute the decoherence rate?

**My thoughts:**

No, because here we cannot use that $|\epsilon\rangle\langle\epsilon|$ or $|\epsilon\rangle\langle\epsilon|^{\otimes n}$ is unchanged, since $\mathcal{E}(|\epsilon\rangle\langle\epsilon|)\neq |\epsilon\rangle\langle\epsilon|$! We would have to consider all parts of the density matrix and write it respective to the basis $|0\rangle,|\epsilon\rangle$ (or $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$ ??) to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fact one needs to answer any question of this sort really comes from a definition:
$$\mathcal{E}^{\otimes n}(\sigma_1\otimes \sigma_2\otimes\cdots\otimes\sigma_n)=\mathcal{E}(\sigma_1)\otimes\mathcal{E}( \sigma_2)\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathcal{E}(\sigma_n).$$ You can use this to compute the effect of the overall channel on any basis state, simply affecting the off-diagonal elements of each $\sigma_i$, then build up the action on any state by taking linear combinations of basis states.

For the state in question, we collect terms and write
\begin{align}
|GHZ\rangle\langle GHZ|&=\frac{1}{K}\left[\left(|0\rangle\langle 0|\right)^{\otimes n}+\left(|0\rangle\langle \epsilon|\right)^{\otimes n}+\left(|\epsilon\rangle\langle 0|\right)^{\otimes n}+\left(|\epsilon\rangle\langle \epsilon|\right)^{\otimes n}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{K}\left[\left(|0\rangle\langle 0|\right)^{\otimes n}+\left(c|0\rangle\langle 0|+s|0\rangle\langle 1|\right)^{\otimes n}+\left(c|0\rangle\langle 0|+s|1\rangle\langle 0|\right)^{\otimes n}+\left(c^2|0\rangle\langle 0|+s^2|1\rangle\langle 1|+cs|1\rangle\langle 0|+cs|0\rangle\langle 1|\right)^{\otimes n}\right].
\end{align} Using the definition of the channel acting on a set of states, we find (using $c$ and $s$ as shorthand for the cosine and sine terms)
\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}^{\otimes n}(|GHZ\rangle\langle GHZ|)=\frac{1}{K}\left\{\mathcal{E}\left[\left(|0\rangle\langle 0|\right)\right]^{\otimes n}+\mathcal{E}\left[\left(c|0\rangle\langle 0|+s|0\rangle\langle 1|\right)\right]^{\otimes n}+\mathcal{E}\left[\left(c|0\rangle\langle 0|+s|1\rangle\langle 0|\right)\right]^{\otimes n}+\mathcal{E}\left[\left(c^2|0\rangle\langle 0|+s^2|1\rangle\langle 1|+cs|1\rangle\langle 0|+cs|0\rangle\langle 1|\right)\right]^{\otimes n}\right\}.
\end{align}
As before, we only need to worry about terms $|0\rangle\langle 1|$ and $|1\rangle\langle 0|$, so we find
\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}^{\otimes n}(|GHZ\rangle\langle GHZ|)=\frac{1}{K}\left[\left(|0\rangle\langle 0|\right)^{\otimes n}+\left(c|0\rangle\langle 0|+se^{-\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle 1|\right)^{\otimes n}+\left(c|0\rangle\langle 0|+se^{-\gamma t}|1\rangle\langle 0|\right)^{\otimes n}+\left(c^2|0\rangle\langle 0|+s^2|1\rangle\langle 1|+cse^{-\gamma t}|1\rangle\langle 0|+cse^{-\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle 1|\right)^{\otimes n}\right].
\end{align}

The properties of this final state can be inspected in any manner you like. One straightforward thing to compute is the reduced state of any of the qubits, which will all be identical and equal to
$$[(1+2c^n+c^2)|0\rangle\langle 0|+s^2|1\rangle\langle 1|+se^{-\gamma t}(c^{n-1}+c)(|1\rangle\langle 0|+|0\rangle\langle 1|)]/(K),$$
which for $n=1$ is
$$[(1+c)^2|0\rangle\langle 0|+s^2|1\rangle\langle 1|+se^{-\gamma t}(1+c)(|1\rangle\langle 0|+|0\rangle\langle 1|)]/(2+2c).$$

---

We can compare this final state to the putative state one would get from simply enacting $|0\rangle\langle \epsilon|\to e^{-\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle \epsilon|$. We only need to consider the $n=1$ case to show that the results differ. For this supposed transformation, we would get, up to normalization
\begin{align}
|0\rangle\langle 0|+|\epsilon\rangle\langle \epsilon|+|0\rangle\langle \epsilon|+|\epsilon\rangle\langle 0|\to &|0\rangle\langle 0|+|\epsilon\rangle\langle \epsilon|+e^{-\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle \epsilon|+e^{-\gamma t}|\epsilon\rangle\langle 0|\\
&=|0\rangle\langle 0|+c^2|0\rangle\langle 0|+s^2|1\rangle\langle 1|+cs(|1\rangle\langle 0|+|0\rangle\langle 1|)+ce^{-\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle 0|+se^{-\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle 1|+ce^{-\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle 0|+se^{-\gamma t}|1\rangle\langle 0|\\
&=(1+c^2+2ce^{-\gamma t})|0\rangle\langle 0|+s^2 |1\rangle\langle 1|+s(e^{-\gamma t}+c)(|1\rangle\langle 0|+|0\rangle\langle 1|).
\end{align} One only difference (for $n=1$) is the $2ce^{-\gamma t}|0\rangle\langle 0|$ term, which is enough to show the two strategies to be different and this latter strategy to be incorrect, but you may still argue that in the $t\to\infty$ limit this difference would disappear. The more important difference is comparing the coefficient $se^{-\gamma t}(1+c)$ from the former strategy to $s(e^{-\gamma t}+c)$ from the latter. In the $t\to\infty$ limit these give different results: the channel I defined at the beginning will have not off-diagonal terms $|0\rangle\langle 1|+|1\rangle\langle 0|$, while the channel defined in this section would retain those off-diagonals with a coefficient $cs$.

Comment: I still don't understand how one could argue from your second last equation that one only has to consider the off diagonal ($|\epsilon\rangle\langle 0|$) to calculate the decoherence rate. As one can tell from your calculation there are off diagonals $|0\rangle\langle 1|$ that originate from e.g. $|\epsilon\rangle\langle\epsilon|$.

Comment: @manuel459 exactly, I agree with you! You were correct in your original post when you said "My thoughts: No"

Comment: Oh, sorry I must be slow off the mark... Thank you for the clarification! Let me add one more detail: What do you think is the interpretation of the off diagonals that came up and are other than $|\epsilon\rangle\langle\epsilon|$? If we say $|0\rangle$ and $|\epsilon\rangle$ are two states "alive" and "dead" of a cat... does the cat totally change state? Because in the end, density matrices are not distinct or unique. Is it possible to rearrange said (second last) equation in your answer to get back to the interpretation coming from $|0\rangle\langle 0$ and $|\epsilon\rangle\langle \epsilon$?

Comment: @manuel459 it's a bit hard to directly answer, because $|\epsilon\rangle$ is already some state where the cat is in a superposition of being alive and dead. I updated the answer to show that one cannot rearrange the answer to get back to the incorrect interpretation. The point is that the decoherence mechanism here is specifically tailored to this set of basis states; one could imagine decoherence that reduced the off-diagonal elements in another orthonormal basis. Decoherence for a non-orthogonal basis is a bit strange, although I'm sure one could cook up some dynamics that induced such

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Oh and I totally understand - you'd consider 000 and 111 as alive and dead. But wouldn't it just mean then that the situation just isn't as "linear" as for the original ghz state? You'd just have (whatever) different state than the generalized ghz state (which is there for t=0) during evolution. If that means that visually, the cat is changing "appearance" is again a very different question.

Comment: @manuel459 Yes so the difference in the limit of infinite decoherence boils down to the final state $|0\rangle\langle 0|+|\epsilon\rangle\langle \epsilon|$ being different from $|0\rangle\langle 0|+|1\rangle\langle 1|$; both are legitimate quantum states but each has different properties